# Create QGIS Plugin UI with QGIS Designer - style like original tools

Tags: qgis-plugins, qt-designer

I developed a QGIS Plugin with QGIS Designer but my UI does not look as nice as original QGIS Tools and I was wondering if its possible to make them as good looking.

Specifically, I don't manage to create a nice explanation box like the ones of the original QGIS tools. In the following example, the titel has a higher font and the whole box can be dynamically made smaller or bigger. Any ideas on how this can be done or perhabs a useful link I missed?

[image]

Comment: You can take a look at the .ui which can be found in your QGIS 3 directory, e.g.: `C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.8/apps/qgis/python/plugins/processing/ui/DlgAlgorithmBase.ui` or from [this link](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/ui/DlgAlgorithmBase.ui)

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot shows the dialog of a processing script. You can create your own scripts by subclassing the `QgsProcessingAlgorithm` class and re-implementing its methods. The explanation box in your screenshot is achieved simply by re-implementing the `shortHelpString()` method and returning the text you wish to appear in the explanation box as a string.

There are several good tutorials with templates for writing processing scripts in QGIS 3:

https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html

https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/processing_python_scripts.html

https://anitagraser.com/2018/03/25/processing-script-template-for-qgis3/

If you want to package a script or collection of scripts into a plugin, you can use Plugin Builder to create a processing plugin which will add a provider in the processing toolbox, containing your custom algorithms.

https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/processing.html